# Will changing password of a Google account revoke access to it on a lost device?

Tags: google-account, accounts

I had a Samsung Galaxy Star Pro Duos with my Google account logged in to the apps (Google+, Gmail...). Now it is lost. I can remotely remove all my accounts from the web browser, but I do not know how to remove it from the device without having it turned on and sync enabled, as sync was disabled and it is currently switched off .

I was thinking if I change my password, my account on that phone would stop syncing and request for the password to be re-entered. Once someone turns it on, and tries to sync, the account must stop.

Will this plan work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your password will require all devices to reauthorize (log in) before syncing any new data, however information already on the device, like bookmarks and such, will remain.
Locking the device with Android Device Manager would be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is already provided by the tool [Android Device Manager](http://android.com/devicemanager) by Google. You log in with your Google account and will see all the devices connected to that account. There you can lock it with a password: if someone tries to turn it on he will be prompted to insert the psw to use it. Since lollipop even a factory reset shouldn't be enough to bypass this lock, because the phone remembers the account it was connected to. But on this point I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score -1):

If you report it stolen it will have a blacklisted ESN. Someone can easily reflash your phone like brand new out of the box. and phones with a bad ESN don't bother people in South America.

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the question at all.